# Unable to attach multiple entities for insertion (An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I have an entity that contains a list of other entities.  The list of entities contains a primary key (identity), foreign key and a string.  When I try to attach the parent entity, I get the exception `An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key`.

For some reason the Entity Framework (EF) thinks that this is a duplicate record.  The records *do have the same foreign key*, but property that is the primary key (Id of type int) is set to 0 which, from my understanding, is acceptable since the column is an identity column.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same primary key values are not allowed if you **attach** the objects to the context. It's only possible if you **add** them to the context.

If you want to insert children for an already existing parent, you can try the following (example for EF >= 4.1):

```
// put parent and all children into Added state
context.Parents.Add(parent);

// reset state for parent to Unchanged, but not for the children
context.Entry(parent).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

context.SaveChanges();
```

I am assuming that parent and all children were detached from the context before this code snippet.

**Edit**

With `ObjectContext`:

```
// put parent and all children into Added state
objectContext.Parents.AddObject(parent);

// reset state for parent to Unchanged, but not for the children
objectContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(parent,EntityState.Unchanged);

objectContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Is this possible with the ObjectContext class?

Comment: @Ek0nomik: I think the code in my Edit is the version for ObjectContext.