# Changing entity state for a list of related entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

This code:

```
orderContext.ShippingOrders.AddObject(shippingOrder);
orderContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(shippingOrder, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);

foreach (var shippingOrderItem in shippingOrder.ShippingOrderItems) {
    //Exception happens here.
    orderContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(shippingOrderItem, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
}
```

Results in this exception: `AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key values are unique before calling AcceptChanges`.  The exception message seems confusing to me as I only have 1 object that is part of the relationship (shippingOrderItem), so there couldn't be a duplicate key.

The parent object (shippingOrder) is in a detached state and I don't want to insert new shippingOrderItems; I want to update existing ones.  How can I change their state to be modified?

The pseudo class structure for the object I am working with looks like this:

```
public class ShippingOrder {
    public List<ShippingOrderItem> ShippingOrderItems { get; set; }
}

public class ShippingOrderItem {
    //This is the where I need to insert new records!  Everything else is an update.
    public List<ShippingOrderItemSerialNumber> ShippingOrderItemSerialNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Using `AddObject` for this scenario doesn't seem right. (`AddObject` is for INSERT but you want an UPDATE). I'd propose to remove the first line and to try again.

Comment: @Slauma - I appreciate the response.  I'm having a hard time figuring out how to approach this.  If you see my previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792566/unable-to-attach-multiple-entities-for-insertion-an-object-with-the-same-key-al) you brought up a good point that I need to add the object since I have related entities that I need to insert.  But, now when I add the object, I can't change the other related entities that I don't want to be inserted; I want them to be updated.  Do you have any ideas?  I updated this question with my class structure.

Comment: Did you try to remove the first line in your first code snippet above? In my opinion, it should work then. Or do you get the same/another error? For updating it is important of course that order and order items all have the correct primary key property value set.

Comment: Aaah, I see now why you use `AddObject`: You want to insert those serial number collection items, but update the other entities in the object graph, right?

Comment: @Slauma - Exactly!  That's what I'm trying to do.  I always work with objects in a detached state so I can cache the data on the server.  Then I pass the data to my controllers and build view models using AutoMapper.  I end up building my entity objects again with AutoMapper once I am done with them in the view, and now here I am.  I'm trying to update all the objects *except* for the serial number collections; those I want to insert.   One idea that I have is to just add arbitrary id's for the serial numbers and then I can attach the object without a key error.  Do you have a different idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of the lines in your code matters. I cannot explain, why. But I could reproduce your error and solved it by swapping some lines in your code:

```
using (var orderContext = new ShippingEntities())
{
    orderContext.ShippingOrders.AddObject(shippingOrder);
    foreach (var shippingOrderItem in shippingOrder.ShippingOrderItems)
    {
        orderContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(
            shippingOrderItem, EntityState.Modified);
    }
    orderContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(
        shippingOrder, EntityState.Modified);

    orderContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

This updates `shippingOrder` and all `shippingOrder.ShippingOrderItems` and inserts all `ShippingOrderItemSerialNumbers`. The primary key property values for `shippingOrder` and `shippingOrder.ShippingOrderItems` must be correct and correspond to existing rows in the database. The primary key property values for the `ShippingOrderItemSerialNumbers` don't matter, you can leave them all `0` (if they are autogenerated identities in the database).

Comment: That did the trick!  Thanks for your help Slauma, it's appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You want to Attach it and then mark is as modified (AddObject is for adding something that will be an insert, as Slauma says).

RIA does this enough that they added an extension method to do the 2 for you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423414(VS.110).aspx

However, it's pretty simple to do yourself, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I originally tried to use `Attach`, but was unable to because I have some related entities that I do want inserted.  I raised this issue in a previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792566/unable-to-attach-multiple-entities-for-insertion-an-object-with-the-same-key-al).  What would be the best way to go about updating my parent object, and then updating a related set of entities further down the object hierarchy?  I updated my post with my pseudo class structure to help make it clear.